# Is there a way that if you stand on a block, and you have a score of 3 for an objective, and then you get a title?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently making a gamemode for my server.
I want to make a sort of quiz that determines in what group you will be placed. I have 4 groups. You do the quiz and it counts your answers.

For example: You have answered 3 of 5 times a specific group, and you are at the end of the quiz. You spawn at a block, and then you get a title in you screen that says: You have joined that group.

Is it possible to do this without plugins?
If not, what plugin do i need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way to do this. You need to figure out what your minimum score is that you want, in your case it is 3. Then if you want to reset the scoreboard, you need to make sure that you have a link to another command block setting it to 0. However, for what you have asked, you will need to use this command:

`/testfor @p[score_TEST=3,score_TEST_min=3]`

Hope this will help : )

Also to get your title, all you have to do is to find what title you want and add it in, but I am assuming you know how to do that.

Comment: Don't add external email addresses in your post, people are expected to use the comment to discuss the problems of the post